# Was the Fantastic 4 reboot movie supposed to be in the same universe as X-Men?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, fantastic-four

Before the release of the *Fantastic Four (2015)*, I remember they were promoting the movie along with the X-Men star cast, at the Comic Con.

There were a lot of talks that it might be in the same universe.

So, I know the movie was disappointing and was a disaster, but if it wasn't, and if they had continued making its sequels, was it meant to share the X-Men universe ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes and no.

In an interview with JoBlo, X-Men franchise writer/producer Simon Kinsberg mentioned that the Fantastic Four reboot takes place in a shared Fox/Marvel universe along with X-Men and Deadpool.

> *"Well this movie take space chronologically before those other films,
> so **it’s more like those films have to acknowledge this than we
> acknowledge Gambit, Deadpool, or Fantastic Four or anything else that
> exists within the sort of Fox/Marvel universe.** But I work on all of
> those films in one capacity or another, either as a producer on all of
> them and as a writer on Fantastic Four and this movie, so I’m
> certainly aware of all the different stories we’re telling at the same
> time, and **they all are part of a larger fabric now,** and so the world
> of Deadpool, the world of Gambit, exists in a post-Days of Future Past
> post-Apocalypse world where all of these stories are the same as our
> shared history.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SIMON KINBERG TALKS TIMELINES, NEW MUTANTS, WOLVERINE & MORE FOR APOCALYPSE](http://www.joblo.com/movie-news/simon-kinberg-talks-timelines-new-mutants-wolverine-more-for-apocalypse-138)</sup></sub>

That being said, we're advised (in a different interview) that although they're in the same *cinematic* universe, they're not in the same fictional universe.

> *"**They exist in parallel universes,**" "Fantastic Four" producers Simon
> Kinberg and Hutch Parker told the Daily News in a joint email.*
>
> *"The Fantastic 4 live in a world without mutants. And **the X-Men live
> in a world without the Fantastic 4."***
>
> <sub><sup>[No Fantastic Four, X-Men crossover: They don’t exist in same cinematic universe, producers tell the Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/movies/fantastic-x-men-not-film-universe-article-1.2314517)</sup></sub>

As to your question of whether a *crossover* was mooted, the answer is that it would have been unlikely. The team's powers are only superheroic in a context where there [aren't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockslide_(comics)) already [other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_(Marvel_Comics)) mutants [who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestar) have [similar](http://x-men.wikia.com/wiki/Cipher) powers.

> **Q. Does the Fantastic Four movie you wrote and the X-Men live in the same universe?**
>
> **Kinsberg:** *Well, it's complicated. Because none of the X-Men movies have
> acknowledged the notion of a sort of superhero team -- the Fantastic
> Four. And the Fantastic Four acquire powers, so for them to live in a
> world where mutants are prevalent is kind of complicated, because
> you're like, "Oh, you're just a mutant." Like, "What's so fantastic
> about you?"*
>
> **Q. "We have powers ... just like that team down the street."**
>
> **Kinsberg:** *Right, right. Exactly, "So, I guess we'll go to school now. We'll go
> to Xavier's school." No, it is, **they live in discrete universes.***
>
> <sub><sup>['Fantastic Four' Writer-Producer Simon Kinberg on Shared Universes and the Challenges of an Origin Story](http://screencrush.com/fantastic-four-x-men/?trackback=tsmclip)</sup></sub>

Comment: Interestingly, the headline from the second quote ("*They don’t exist in same cinematic universe, producers tell the Daily News*") is **exactly the opposite of what the producers are saying** which is that there's scope for a crossover. This belies a lack of understanding from the article's writer and shouldn't be taken as confirmation of anything.

Comment: [Possibly interesting article](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Don-t-Expect-See-X-Men-Fantastic-Four-Reboot-42979.html)

Comment: @Edlothiad - Good find. It directly addresses the likelihood of a crossover event had the film been a critical and box-office success.

Comment: Yeah, I don't doubt they'd have jumped on the "joined universe" bandwagon if they were actually any good at making superhero movies. Unfortunately, all they have is X-Men and Deadpool, neither of which are well-suited for that kind of approach, especially now that they don't have the pull of Hugh Jackman, Patrick Stewart and Ian McKellen to draw in a wider audience.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - They've set up the "next gen" though. It's clear that they're gonna keep churning these out. We can also look forward to a Fantastic 4 reboot in about ten years.

Comment: Probably sooner if they wanna prevent the rights reverting back to Marvel.

Comment: “As to your question of whether a crossover was mooted, the answer is that it would have been unlikely.” If the movie has been more successful, I reckon it would have been a certainty. Every studio wants an *Avengers*-level success, and [Reed Richards finding ways to travel to other universes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_versions_of_Mister_Fantastic#Marvel_Zombies) isn’t exactly without precedent.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I can't see it happening. The Fantastic Four's powers are nothing special in the X-Men universe. Invisibility? Force-Fields? Flight and flames? Ho-Hum.

Comment: @Valorum: I’m not clear how that would convince a studio executive to not pursue box-office billions by imitating *Avengers*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It's important to remember that the studio is going to be petrified of damaging their franchise. That's why all the X-men movies are like a sitcom, the same characters put into different situations